# No overload matches this call - moment js

Tags: node.js, typescript, momentjs

I have the following code:

```
const calibrationSpan = parent.CalibrationCycleID;
const lastCalibrationDate = parent.LastCalibrationDate;

const amountSpan: number = CycleCodes[calibrationSpan];

const calibrationDueDate = moment(lastCalibrationDate).add(amountSpan, calibrationSpan[0]).toDate();

console.log('span', calibrationSpan) 
console.log('dues', calibrationDueDate)

return calibrationDueDate;
```

It tells me No overload matches this call on the momentjs add function. If I log calibration span, it's a string from which I just grab the first char (d, m, y) .
However if I have it like this

```
const calibrationDueDate = moment(lastCalibrationDate).add(amountSpan, "d");
```

it runs as it should. any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript does not know calibrationSpan type. You can cast the `calibrationSpan[0] as DurationInputArg2` to notify typescript `calibrationSpan[0]` has one of the types in DurationInputArg2 (e.g. "d", "m", "y")

1st way:

```js
import { DurationInputArg2 } from 'moment';

...

const calibrationDueDate = moment(lastCalibrationDate).add(amountSpan, calibrationSpan[0] as DurationInputArg2).toDate();

...
```

2nd way, cast `calibrationSpan` as `DurationInputArg2[]`

```
import { DurationInputArg2 } from 'moment';

...

const calibrationSpan = parent.CalibrationCycleID as DurationInputArg2[];

...

const calibrationDueDate = moment(lastCalibrationDate).add(amountSpan, calibrationSpan[0]).toDate();

...
```